# iOS 11 UINavigationBar Position Loses Status Bar Height During Transition

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11, childviewcontroller, safearealayoutguide

This bug has cropped up in iOS 11. There is a UINavigationController embedded as a child UIViewController of another UIViewController. There's a UIPanGestureRecogniser setup that affects the y axis of the child UIViewController's view's frame allowing you to drag it down to reveal the UIViewController below

The problem that's cropped up is that now as soon as the UIViewController's frame gets adjusted to move it downwards iOS seems to remove the inset on the UINavigationBar for the UIStatusBar, which results in an unpleasant jerk upwards.

[image: Status Bar Animation Bar]

How do I prevent this from happening?